# Not able to Get Amazon Cognito Identity from Twitter Authentication using Jquery or .Net

Tags: javascript, jquery, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I am trying to get Amazon Web Services(AWS) Cognito Identity from Twitter Authentication(Access Token), but I am not getting any result.

It is working fine in the case of Facebook, Amazon & Google Account. In the case of Twitter authentication, I can't find any Cognito JavaScript SDK that I can use to retrieve the Cognito Identity once I have authenticated with Twitter (the way it works for the other Identity providers mentioned above).

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3):

Twitter authentication tokens have two parts: the *token key* and the *token secret*. To authenticate your users in Cognito with Twitter, you need to pass them both separated by a `";"` like this (assuming you are using the [AWS JavaScript SDK](https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-browser/)):

```
new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
    IdentityPoolId: 'IDENTITY_POOL_ID',
    Logins: {
        'api.twitter.com': twitterTokenKey+";"+twitterTokenSecret
    }
});
```

As you can see, the provider is just a string that is sent to the Amazon Cognito service, so the SDK itself doesn't need to specifically support Twitter or Facebook, Google, etc. for it to work.